# Is the keystream recovered by tkiptun-ng the same key used to encrypt all data frames between the client and the AP?

Tags: wireless, aircrack-ng, wpa-enterprise, tkip

Looking at the manual for tkiptun-ng,(http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=tkiptun-ng) The output saves the keystream in the example near the end of the program. Is this the same keystream used to encrypt all the data traffic?(i.e the PTK?) Does this mean that once I have this keystream, I am then able to decrypt all traffic between the client and the AP? (Assuming that the keys are not rotated)